# Using $this to call static property .. should it work?

Tags: php, oop

I learned that we can't use `$this::` to call static class property and should use `self::` or `static::`
so any idea why this code works ?

```
<?php

class Test 
{

    public static string $test = 'test';

    public function it(): void
    {
        echo $this::$test;
    }
}


(new Test())->it();
```

Comment: `$this` refers to the instantiated object, and you echo the static value `$test`, hence `::`. These two also work: `echo self::$test;`, and `echo Test::$test;`. There are many ways to refer to the same class.

Comment: Looks like more of an answer than a comment. What clarification are you seeking? You are not new here.

Comment: [PHP: Why am I getting errors about static properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6337543/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: [PHP Static Keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Static properties are accessed using the Scope Resolution Operator (::) and cannot be accessed through the object operator (->).

And here is the important part:

> It's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value cannot be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

So you can access static properties, static methods, and static constants with $this – which is a variable – within a class definition's code.

And in your code above you could also access the $test property from the outside of the class via the instance $test:

```
echo $test::$test;   // This works in addition to: echo Test::$test;
```

Other languages support the call of static members via the instance variable too (for example Java, Python, VB.NET, C++, etc.).

Comment: Because it was implemented. Search for 'Added support for dynamic access of static members using $foo::myFunc(). (Etienne Kneuss)' within https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0.

Comment: Yes, sure, I've checked it was implemented, but looking for the docs, that was all^^ +1 anyway. The missing sentence (I missed it) was _"reference the **class** using a variable [bold by me]"_.

Answer (score 0):

You can access static property or call static method with `$this`, but you can not refer `$this` inside/within a static method as it's not an instance context.

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
> without needing an instantiation of the class. These can also be
> accessed statically within an instantiated class object.

> ... Because
> static methods are callable without an instance of the object created,
> the pseudo-variable `$this` is not available inside methods declared as
> static.

Comment: @hakre https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Thanks, now seeing it, Lukas also had it already in their answer ^^.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this works since PHP 5.3.0, *$this* is scope-resolved by *::* for it's class-name when accessing the static class member *Test::$test*:

```
class Test 
{
    
    public static $test = 'test';
    
    public function it()
    {
        echo $this::$test;
    }
}  
    
$test = new Test();
$test->it();
```

```
test
```

*(Output for 5.3.0-29, 5.4.0-45, 5.5.0-38, 5.6.0-40, 7.0.0-33, 7.1.0-33, 7.2.0-34, 7.3.0-33, 7.4.0-33, 8.0.0-30, 8.1.0-22, 8.2.0-9)*

- https://3v4l.org/83IjC#v530

Before PHP 5.3 it was a *"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM|T_STRING"*.

As [lukas.j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17218429/lukas-j) pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941123/using-this-to-call-static-property-should-it-work/76941407?noredirect=1#comment135642380_76941407) (thanks!) this is documented in the PHP 5.3 change-log:

> Added support for dynamic access of static members using $foo::myFunc(). (Etienne Kneuss)

- https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0

The scope resolution operator :: is much older, this is PHP 3 terrain.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: It is documented. Search for 'Added support for dynamic access of static members using $foo::myFunc(). (Etienne Kneuss)' within https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0.

Comment: @lukas.j: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I made your comment now more prominent in the answer, as I think this is what I was looking for. I also need to re-read the operators docs, but I think the rule is just that the classname of the object is taken. Upvoted [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76941310/367456).